# using html vector markup language

Tags: html, vml

I have to use [VML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/VML/web-workshop---specs---standards----introduction-to-vector-markup-language--vml-) for outlook Desktop client's html email .
This is my code

```
   <html>
  <head>
    <xml:namespace ns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" prefix="v" />
    <style>v\: * { behavior:url(#default#VML); display:inline-block }</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <v:oval style="width:100pt;height:50pt" fillcolor="red">
</v:oval>
  </body>
</html>
```

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KGKmKe)

But the `oval` doesn't display at all . What am I missing ?